# How to bind XAML elements to custom class in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows Store App and trying to bind some XAML elements to a custom class:

```
namespace My.Name.Space {
    public class AppSettings {
        private static AppSettings _instance = new AppSettings();
        public AppSettings Settings { get { return _instance; } 

        private static bool SomeOption {
            get {
                ...
                return option;
            }
        }
    }
}


<!-- ResourceDict will be merged to the Application.Resources -->
<ResourceDictionary 
   ...
   xmlns:myNS="clr-namespace:My.Name.Space">

   <myNS:AppSettings x:Key="AppSettings"/>
</ResourceDictionary>


<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Settings.SomeOption, Source={StaticResource AppSettings} .../>
```

This works without any problem in a Windows Phone 8 App. But when trying to compile the same code in a Windows Store App the compiler says:

> Unknown Type "AppSettings" in XML-Namespace "clr-namespace:My.Name.Space;assembly=MyAppProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

So, what can I do to bind a XAML element to my Settings class?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have found closing VS and reopening has resolved a few issues similar to this. To avoid issues I tend to name the key different to the class and avoid using 'reserved' type names on classes. Sorry its not the best answer (hence comment, not answer), just thought I'd try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

`xmlns:myNS="clr-namespace:My.Name.Space">`

to

`xmlns:myNS="using:My.Name.Space">`